# Solve $\frac{dv}{dt} = 32.2 - a v^2$ by transforming it into a Riccati equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following equation:

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = 32.2 - a v^2$$

with $a$ being a constant.

I'm stuck. The only hint I have is that with some kind of transformation the equation becomes a Riccati type ODE. Even if I get there, as far as I know I need a solution for it to get the whole solution. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think this will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation#Conversion_to_a_second_order_linear_equation

Comment: You can solve the ODE as a Riccati equation, or as a separable equation: $$\int\frac{dv}{32.2-av^2}=\int dt.$$